# Checkpoint-admin issue(deploy oracle)

Tags: go-ethereum, oracles

I want to embed my private network in the geth client and I need to create a checkpoint for that.
I found out information that they are created using checkpoint-admin and deploy oracle in it. But I can't do it.

I run clef then geth client like this:

```
geth --signer http://localhost:8550
```

And I run checkpoint-admin:

```
checkpoint-admin deploy --rpc <NODE_RPC_ENDPOINT> --clef <CLEF_ENDPOINT> --signer <SIGNER_TO_SIGN_TX> --signers <TRUSTED_SIGNER_LIST> --threshold 1
```

and this is what it gives out:

> Deploying new checkpoint oracle:
>
> Admin 1 => *Wallet*
>
> Signatures needed to publish: 1 Sending deploy request to Clef...
> Fatal: Failed to deploy checkpoint oracle failed to retrieve account
> nonce: the method eth_getTransactionCount does not exist/is not
> available

and in clef:

> DEBUG[08-08|07:46:48.838] Served account_version                  reqid=1 t=0s
>
> WARN [08-08|07:46:48.848] Served eth_getTransactionCount conn=127.0.0.1:51579 reqid=1 t=0s                       err="the method eth_getTransactionCount does not exist/is not available"
>
> DEBUG[08-08|07:46:48.863] RPC connection read error         err=EOF